# What do "plump" and "stately" mean in this sentence from James Joyce's Ulysses?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, ambiguity, parts-of-speech

The following passage comes at the beginning of James Joyce's masterwork, *Ulysses*, an early twentieth century novel. There are a lot of references to Catholic ritual in it. 
Here, Buck Mulligan, the hero, is about to shave. He is carrying a straight-edge razor, the kind that is mostly used for legitimate purposes by barbers these days, and a bowl of foam, probably produced by shaving soap and a brush.

Are the words *plump* and *stately* adverb or adjective? Do they describe the attitude of Buck Mulligan or his body?

It is necessary to say that both words can according to many dictionaries be either adverb or adjective.

> [Stately, plump Buck Mulligan came from the stairhead](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buck_Mulligan), bearing a bowl of
>   lather on which a mirror and a razor lay crossed. A yellow dressing-gown,
>   ungirdled, was sustained gently behind him by the mild morning air. He held
>   the bowl aloft and intoned :

The German translator has translated this part very ambiguously.

> STATTLICH  UND  FEIST  erschien  Buck  Mulligan  am  Treppenaustritt,  ein  Seifenbecken  in  Händen,  auf  dem  gekreuzt  ein  Spiegel  und  ein  Rasiermesser  lagen.  Ein  gelber  Schlafrock  mit  offenem Gürtel bauschte sich leicht hinter ihm in der milden Morgenluft. Er hielt das Becken in die Höhe und intonierte:

Comment: He appears in the self-satisfied pose of, say, a burgermeister or a monsignor: a substantial presence, somewhat imposing but certainly fodder for a satire of the bourgeoisie of early 19th century Ireland.

Comment: @Robusto Did you mean "early 20th century"?

Comment: I think I see the problem. [Collins dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/german-english/stattlich) says that *stattlich* means *magnificent, strapping, imposing, impressive, large* or *handsome*. None of these seems very much like the English definition of [*stately*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/stately) that applies here: which is *dignified*.

Comment: @WS2: Yes, of course. I was thinking of June 16, 1904 (Bloomsday) and my idiot brain said "19th century!"

Comment: I don't understand why you think it's an either/or. Why can't *plump* refer to Buck's body and *stately* refer to his manner?

Comment: In this context I would interpret "stately" (which is an adjective) to mean "tall" or "erect".

Answer (score 1):

Plump would mean something like "fat" or perhaps more metaphorically, bloated, full of himself. Stately would mean something like dignified, ceremonial, lofty.

Comment: I know, what they mean . describe thez here the body of the character or his stance ?

Comment: @kazhvan here are some other answers, a few of them good: https://www.quora.com/What-does-Joyce-mean-by-Stately-plump-Buck-Mulligan-came-from-the-stairhead-bearing-a-bowl-of-lather-on-which-a-mirror-and-a-razor-lay-crossed.

Comment: I have already read the answers there. They are very confusing

Comment: @kazhvan I would say that neither word can be an adverb, both are adjectives. It would be ungrammatical to say "He sits plump" or "She walks stately" (although both sentences might occur in non-standard dialect speech). In this case Joyce is using both words to describe Mulligan. 'Plump' describes him physically and 'stately' describes his style of walking and his presentation but both relate to him. The only verb in the same clause as 'plump' and 'stately' is 'came' and neither modifier affects that verb.

Comment: Plump could also imply rich -- rich men are often portrayed as overweight in period pieces because they could afford more and richer foods.

Comment: @Barmar -- right, 'well-fed' might be a nice way to put it, as compared with Stephen Dedalus, who is quite poor and perhaps quite hungry (similar to Joyce while in Paris, but this would get into quite a long tangent...). But anyways, yes "plump/fat" would imply that person can afford to be fat and is certainly not poor.

Answer (score 0):

TvF is correct. In the original publication of Ulysses, the first page is a great big letter S, with a tiny comma, then the word 'plump' - next page  - Buck Mulligan came...  so, the word stately is an adverb, referring to how he came down the stairhead - it could have said, "In a stately manner, plump Buck..." Plump is the following adjective, describing Buck physically. "Plump Buck Mulligan" is the description. Whose walk is stately. The confusing thing is, without the comma, the sentence would also work. But in that case, since stately can be either an adverb or adjective, "Stately plump Buck Mulligan came down..." would describe Mulligan and being both stately and plump in appearance. In the actual sentence, he's plump in appearance and stately in the way he walks down the stairhead. Which makes him a more comical figure than the other way of reading it.

Answer (score -2):

*Stately* is the adverb, describing *how* he 'came from the stairhead'.

*Plump* is the adjective, describing Buck Mulligan.

Using different adverbs and adjectives (changing the meaning), it is easier to see:
*Quickly, fat Buck came from the stairhead.*

It is also easier to understand if you re-order the sentence (without changing its meaning):
*Plump Buck Mulligan came quickly from the stairhead.*

Comment: And the German translator obviously didn't understand that because he translated both as adjectives.

Comment: "Stately" is an adjective -- look it up!

Comment: @HotLicks I did. Stately can also be used as an adverb, see https://www.dictionary.com/browse/stately or https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stately . Please do not just read the first entry in a dictionary but take time to read the question, the poem, the context (poetry, verse) and think about it.

Comment: "Stately" *can* be an adverb, but it's usually an adjective, and in the stated context it's clearly on par with "plump", another adjective.

Comment: Sorry, that 'clearly' is just opinion. Please add something to found this on beyond 'usually it's an adjective, so clearly it's here, too'. Clearly, the OP didn't think it was that clear, or she wouldn't have asked that question.

Comment: And, obviously, I might be wrong. But given that the OP already stated that she knew it can be both an adverb or adjective, it adds zero value to the conversation to say: 'it's an adjective, look it up'.